# Convert a CSV containing text file to excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I am creating a script that will convert a text file to excel. This contains data like this:

```
1,20131223100043,0,G1,0,0,918814873380,1,1,0,....73 items ;
1,20131223100042,0,G1,0,0,918814873381,1,1,0,....73 items ;
1,20131223100073,0,G1,0,0,918814873382,1,1,0,....73 items ;
....
...
atleast 1000 lines.
```

I have managed to write a single line to excel, but I am clueless how to write a whole text file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
#coding: utf8
import xlwt
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('sheet 1')

#Create a style for font and its size for first line
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font = xlwt.Font()
font.name = 'Arial'
#font.bold = True
font.height = 220
# Set the style's font to this new one you set up
style.font = font

#split lines
string1 = '1,20131223100043,0,G1,0,0,918814873380,1,1,0....all 73 items'
list1 = string1.decode('utf-8').split(',')

for i in range(1, 73):
sheet.write(1,i-1,list1[i-1], style)
wbk.save('text11.xls')
```

Any other approach is also welcomed.

Comment: What's wrong with opening csv file directly in excel?

Comment: As I said, it contains csv data, but it is a .txt file

Comment: If the file "contains CSV data", then it is a CSV file. The file extension should not matter. You might have to force Excel to show "All Files" when you open though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using the well known [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library. It has routines to load from CSV and [save to excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).